# Fix DropDown Menu On Right Side And Nav Menu

Tags: html, css, mobile, drop-down-menu, navbar

I have two questions about my dropdown menu

1. When I open my dropdown menu its on the right and not underneath. How can I change this?

Sub-Menu Was Right its Okay

[image: How To Chang Position to Bellow]

2. When I open with my PC its ok, but its glitching in mobile mode (Android). How to fix my nav menu, its transparent, I want to make background black?

[image: How To Fix Transparat Nav-Menu]

You can see my code here:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/3Lj9b2n9/`

`http://codepen.io/aziu/pen/zBmWaW`
```

Btw, what Tool do you use to troubelshoot HTML and CSS? I am a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** To meet your needs you would need to split the sub menu and the sub-sub menu into different classes so that you can style them differently. See updated code this change.

As far as the tool to use Stack Overflow recommends using the built in Code Snippet tool that you'll see below. To correct your spacing issue you need to get rid of the 180px you set and use something dynamic such as a percentage. In this case setting it to 100% of the width corrects that problem.

Please include more code to look into the mobile issue.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (target.parentElement && target.parentElement.className.indexOf('has-submenu') > -1) {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#menu {
  background: #000;
  color: #eee;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #eeeded
}

#menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #0000ff;
}

#menu ul {
  height: 35px
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font: bold 12px Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  border-left: 1px solid #111;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #000;
}

#menu li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
}

#menu li:hover > a,
#menu li a:hover {
  background: #111
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#menu label {
  font: bold 30px Arial;
  display: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center
}

#menu label span {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px
}

#menu ul.submenu {
  height: auto;
  width: 180px;
  background: #111;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  border: 0;
}

#menu ul.submenu li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font: 12px Arial;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu a.home {
  background: #c00;
}

#menu a.prett {
  padding: 0 27px 0 14px
}

#menu a.prett::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu .has-submenu.open > a.prett::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #eee transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu ul a:hover {
  background: #c00;
}

#menu ul .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #111;
  width: 180px;
}

#menu ul .subsubmenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #111;
  width: 180px;
  left:100%;
  top: 0;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu li {
  background: #111;
}

#menu li.has-submenu.open > .submenu {
  display: block;
 }

#menu li.has-submenu.open > .subsubmenu {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<nav id='menu'>
  <input type='checkbox' />
  <label>&#8801;<span>Navigation</span></label>
  <ul id='menu'>
    <li><a class='home' href='/'>Home</a></li>
    <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' href='#!' title='Kategori Game'>Category Game</a>
      <ul class='submenu'>
        <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' href='#!' title='Kategori Game'>Category Game 1</a>
          <ul class='subsubmenu'>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Terbaik Terpopuler'>GAME TERBAIK</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Android Gratis'>GAME GRATIS</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Android Berbayar'>GAME ( PRO/PREMIMUM )</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Android Online'>GAME ONLINE</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Offline Android'>GAME OFFLINE</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game HD Android 3D'>GAME HD ( 3D )</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' href='#!' title='Kategori Game 2'>Category Game 2</a>
          <ul class='subsubmenu'>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Petualangan RPG'>RPG ( PETUALANGAN )</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Tembak FPS'>FPS ( TEMBAK )</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Balap Racing'>RACING ( BALAPAN )</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Laga Action'>GAME ACTION</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Android Strategi'>GAME STRATEGY</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Android Sports'>GAME SPORTS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' href='#!' title='Kategori Game 3'>Category Game 3</a>
          <ul class='subsubmenu'>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Simulasi'>GAME SIMULASI</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Musik'>GAME MUSIC</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Teka-Teki'>WORD / TEBAK KATA</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Puzzle'>GAME PUZZLE</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Pendidikan'>GAME PENDIDIKAN</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.fullapkz.com/#' title='Game Untuk Anak'>GAME ANAK</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-submenu'><a href='#!' title='Kategori Game'>Category Game</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks For Helping , 
I Say Only Drop Down . Not With Sub-Menu to ...
how to make it sub menu back to right position ?

Comment: @aziu code above is corrected. Please let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Category 1 , 2, 3, bellow CATEGORY GAME ...
Thanks

Comment: @aziu see the updated code, you'll need to adjust the javascript to make the other sub-sub menus go away when you click either of the other two but the styling is there.

Comment: Thanks Man, That Really Help ... I Still Download Snippet and want lern more about it

Comment: @Adam How about Question 2 ? can you fix this ? I Cant Find Colour that cause Nav Menu be Transparat when I Open my Web With Mobile Phone 

Thanks

Comment: @aziu I'm not seeing any of the code that creates that responsive navigation you have above so I can't take a look at it.

Comment: What Name of Code , May Be I Can Paste Here
CSS Code Or HTML ?